# How does Hyperledger Fabric's Exercute-order-validate Architecture work?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am having difficulty understanding how Hyperledger Fabrics' execute-order-validate work. Can someone provide a specific examples and compare/contrast that against an order-execute architecture?

https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2018/02/architecture-hyperledger-fabric/

Answer (score 2):

**order-execute architecture**

**Order**: Transactions are added to the ledger in some order and disseminated to all peers.
**Execute**: Transactions are sequentially executed (e.g. using smart contract code) on all peers.

**execute-order-validate architecture**

**Execute**: Transactions are executed (using chaincode) in any order, possibly even in parallel.
**Order**: When enough peers agree on the results of a transaction, it’s added to the ledger and disseminated to all peers. This step is where the transactions are first given an ordering — until transactions are added to the ledger, there’s no concept of one transaction happening before or after another.
**Validate**: Each peer validates and applies the ledger’s transactions in sequence. Now that the transactions have an ordering, the peers can check whether a later transaction was invalidated by an earlier transaction. For example, this prevents one item from being sold two times (called double-spending).

https://medium.com/kokster/hyperledger-fabric-endorsing-transactions-3c1b7251a709

Answer (score 0):

In bitcoin and Ethereum, all peers execute the transactions in a block, after the transactions have been ordered in a block.
Thus, they operate in a "Order-Execute-Validate" blockchain.

In Fabric - you only need to execute the transaction in a subset of the nodes and not on all of them, and the transaction is executed speculatively and sent to ordering.

Comment: Does this mean that Fabric can never have a PBFT algo on a transaction level ? That is , are we always going to have to use the endorsement policy for a transaction consensus ? Instead of a majority algorithm like PBFT ?

Comment: Right. But an endorsement policy can also be a majority vote, no need for PBFT, RBFT, or IBFT